# How to pass a 'json' parameter with an url in android?

Tags: android, json, wcf, url

I have check-boxes on one page and when user selects a particular check-box, it passes the id associated with it to the next page, on this page I want to send those ids in the form of url to a wcf service.

My url is 
http://rankup.co.uk/service1.svc/getTopic/

After adding the parameters, I want this json to pass with the url like

http://rankup.co.uk/service1.svc/getTopic/20,32

where "20,32" are the ids selected by the user (it may vary accordingly)

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the parameters with the Intent from the calling activity like this

```
intent.putExtra("parameters", "20,32");
```

Then retrieve this parameter from the second activity :

```
String parameters = getIntent().getStringExtra("parameters", 0.0);
```

After that make the url like this :

```
String url = "http://rankup.co.uk/service1.svc/getTopic/ "+parameters;
```

Second part : to get and parse the json you can see this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array list or can create an string variable. On clicking on checkbox, you can add all ids in a comma separated list or array and then can send using intent to the next screen.